Is the periodically driven Duffing's oscillator uniformly hyperbolic?
I am currently trying to figure out whether there is any physical measure (or SRB measure) for a periodically driven Duffing's bi-stable oscillator given by the following differential equations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}&=v
\\
\dot{v}&=x-x^3-\gamma v + f\cos(\omega \tau)
\\
\dot{\tau} &= 1
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\gamma$ is a damping coefficient, $f$ and $\omega$ are the external forcing amplitude and driving frequency, respectively.
I learned that such a measure exists for uniformly hyperbolic systems. Intuitively, the induced 2-dim Poincare map by the continuous dynamic system should be invertible and hence has no zero eigenvalues. Therefore, the system seems to be uniformly hyperbolic. However, I could not prove that hyperbolicity holds for this system.
I wonder whether there is proof that Duffing's system (or the induced Poincare map) is or is not uniformly hyperbolic.
Thanks in advance for any help or information!
